# Use cookies value in model ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, cookies, paperclip

How can I use cookies values in model.

I have a model to upload files using paperclip and added interpolate to pass cookie value. This cookie is set on login to user folder name.

I have an upload model to upload files and want to pass folder name to use in path in following code

```
has_attached_file :upload,
    :url => "/controllers/original/:basename.:extension",
    :path => "/files/uploads/:folder/:basename.:extension"
```

and this is how I use it in controller

```
@upload = Upload.new(params[:upload])
```

so I am not getting how to pass folder name to model, I tried to use interpolates but Local variables are not available there as well so I am stuck in here,

I am trying to do this because I can not get session or current user in model.

Comment: I think my question was not clear so updated it.

Answer (score 6):

From [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html):

> Cookies are read and written through ActionController#cookies.

If you need cookie's value in model, pass them from controller.

If you want a "dynamic" path for paperclip, here is [the documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Interpolations) for it.

Still I don't recommend you to save model data in cookie and rely on it.

Comment: This documentation explains everything, but my requirement is different here, I updated the question.

Comment: @Vikram Why do you need to get `folder` from cookie? What if cookie being deleted? Folder is related to user, isn't it?

Comment: I've also include link to Paperclip's "dynamic" path configuration in my answer, in case you need this

Comment: On my app users needs to upload files daily ( a team ) so I need a folder created each time user is logged in and files uploaded to this new folder.
If a user login on monday, wednesday and friday and upload files I should see 3 different folders - folder name will be like user_sess_sep07